Validating changes on a protobuf file
Say I am using a proto file as my config file. I might change the values of the proto field to update the config. How should I design an automation that checks what I changed conforms to certain rules?
Example
Before Change
A: "some text"
B: {
  C: 1
  D: "1"
}

After Change
A: "other text"
B: {
  C: 2
  D: "3"
}

There are two rules

Field A's value cannot be changed
Field D must be the string representation of field C

How can I detect what was changed and instruction the user on how to fix such thing?
Trying to collect some code design ideas. Much appreciated!
My idea is to detect what is wrong in each version of the proto file individually. Then compare each rule's finding between before change and after change, to derive what was wrong.
However, the "medium" to represent rule findings is hard to decide. And the best way I can think of to compare findings is field by field.
